# Get the number of digits from label ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating labels dynamically and I want to know the number of digits entered in the label so that I can create new labels of that number. i.e. if the digit in the label is "67453848" then I have to get the number of digits in this label here it is "8".

Thank you

Comment: use length Property to count your word

Comment: By default the text in the label will be NSString but not int. In this case you need to use length property as Mayank said. And that would be label.text.length as Igor said in the answer.

Comment: Is your label only going to have digits? If that is the case then you can just use the label.text.length property but if not and it can have digits and others characters mixed, then you need to iterate though the text and check character by character at every position to see if that is a digit or not and based on that increase your counter

Answer (score 1):

you looking for

```
label.text.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

NSLog(@"%d",yourLabel.text.length);